# stripe setup works In dashboard though not in CLI/&DB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, stripe-payments

having stripe issue where the subscriptions go through to stripe, though they don't go through onto Mongo to be checked on after success page.

When checking mongo collection, it doesn't show isSubscribed.

The db ops happen within webhook js with each event as shown

I have had this exact setup/ boilerplate on a different site where everything works fine though not sure if I'm missing a setup with stripe.

Though, on this site-- I am getting errors in stripe CLI even though it's still posting that the subscription went through in the stripe dashboard:

```
2022-05-22 04:34:05            [ERROR] Failed to POST: Post "http://localhost:4242/webhook": dial tcp [::1]:4242: connect: connection refused
```

I have logged into stripe and everything.

My webhook page + index:

webhooks.js

```js
import Stripe from 'stripe';
import { buffer } from 'micro';
import clientPromise from '../../lib/mongodb';

export const config = {
    api: {
        bodyParser: false,
    }
}

const webhookHandler = async (req, res) => {
    const stripe = new Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);

    if (req.method === 'POST') {
        const buf = await buffer(req);
        const sig = req.headers['stripe-signature'];
        const webhookSecret = process.env.STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET;
        let event;
        try {
            if (!sig || !webhookSecret) return;
            event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(buf, sig, webhookSecret);
        } catch (error) {
            return res.status(400).json(`Webhook Error: ${error.message}`);
        }
        const client = await clientPromise;
        const usersCollection = client.db().collection('users');

        // switch (event.type) {
        //     case 'payment_intent.succeeded':
        //         const paymentIntent = event.data.object;
        //         // Then define and call a function to handle the event payment_intent.succeeded
        //         break;
        //     // ... handle other event types
        //     default:
        //         console.log(`Unhandled event type ${event.type}`);
        // }

        if (event.type === 'checkout.session.completed') {
            const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.retrieve(event.data.object.id);
            const user = await usersCollection.findOne({ email: session.customer_email });
            if (!user) {
                res.status(404).json({ message: 'User not found.' });
                return;
            }
            await usersCollection.updateOne({ email: user.email }, {
                $set: {
                    stripeCustomerId: session.customer, stripeSubscriptionId: session.subscription
                }
            });
        }

        if (event.type === 'invoice.paid') {
            const invoice = await stripe.invoices.retrieve(event.data.object.id);
            const subscription = await stripe.subscriptions.retrieve(invoice.subscription);
            const customer = await stripe.customers.retrieve(subscription.customer);
            const user = await usersCollection.findOne({ email: customer.email });
            if (!user) {
                res.status(404).json({ message: 'User not found.' });

                return;
            }
            if (!customer.deleted && subscription.current_period_end) {
                const newEndDate = new Date(subscription.current_period_end * 1000);
                await usersCollection.updateOne({ email: customer.email }, { $set: { subscriptionEndDate: newEndDate } });
            }
        }

        if (event.type === 'customer.subscription.deleted') {
            const subscription = await stripe.subscriptions.retrieve(event.data.object.id);
            const customer = await stripe.customers.retrieve(subscription.customer);
            const user = await usersCollection.findOne({ email: customer.email });
            if (!user) {
                res.status(404).json({ message: 'User not found.' });

                return;
            }
            await usersCollection.updateOne({ email: customer.email }, { $set: { subscriptionEndDate: null } });
        }

        if (event.type === 'customer.subscription.updated') {
            const subscription = await stripe.subscriptions.retrieve(event.data.object.id);
            const customer = await stripe.customers.retrieve(subscription.customer);
            const user = await usersCollection.findOne({ email: customer.email });
            if (!user) {
                res.status(404).json({ message: 'User not found.' });

                return;
            }
            if (!customer.deleted && subscription.current_period_end) {
                const newEndDate = new Date(subscription.current_period_end * 1000);
                await usersCollection.updateOne({ email: customer.email }, { $set: { subscriptionEndDate: newEndDate } });
            }
        }
        res.status(200).send();
    }
}

export default webhookHandler;
```

api/user/index.js

```js
import { getSession } from 'next-auth/react';
import clientPromise from '../../../lib/mongodb';
import dayjs from 'dayjs';

export default async function handler(req, res) {
    if (req.method !== 'GET') {
        return;
    }

    const session = await getSession({ req: req });

    if (!session) {
        res.status(401).json({ message: 'Not authenticated!' });
        return;
    }


    const userEmail = session.user.email;
    const client = await clientPromise;

    const usersCollection = client.db().collection('users');
    const user = await usersCollection.findOne({ email: userEmail });
    console.log(" ~ file: index.js ~ line 23 ~ handler ~ user", user)

    if (!user) {
        res.status(404).json({ message: 'User not found.' });

        return;
    }

    res.status(200).json({ ...user, isSubscribed: dayjs(new Date(user.subscriptionEndDate)).add(2, 'day').isAfter(dayjs()) });
    console.log(" ~ file: index.js ~ line 32 ~ handler ~ isSubscribed", isSubscribed)
}
```

Any info would be helpful

Comment: Have you started the web server on localhost? Most probably [not](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-cli/issues/273).

Comment: @seeker yes I have

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the request hasn't reached your endpoint.

You can verify whether the Stripe event has reached your server by looking at the events log on Dashboard: https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/events. Click on the relevant event (URL should be  https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/events/evt_xx) and checks the "Webhook CLI responses" section
[image]